# Lemma for the Bescicovitch covering lemma

Tags: inequality, angle, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, spheres, triangle-inequality

I want to prove the following lemma

> Lemma (version 1) :
>
> If $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are such that
> $|a-b| > |a| > 0$
> $|a - b| > |b| > 0$
> then the angle between $a,b$ is bounded by below by a costant depending only on $n$, in particolar one has
> $\big| \frac{a}{|a|} - \frac{b}{|b|} \big| \geq 1$

I tried in many ways but I can't find a way to prove this.

The lemma has been stated in this [lecture](https://youtu.be/T5MHpUu1RDI)

Actually I would like to modify the statement, and to prove an inequality of the following type

> Lemma (version 2)
> For each $n$ there exists a $\delta>0$ sufficiently small such that
>
> If $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^n$, are such that
> $|a - b| > (1 - \delta)|a| > 0$ , $|a - b| > (1 - \delta)|b| > 0$, then the angle between $a,b$ is bounded below by a positive fixed costant depending only on $n$ (and possibly on $\delta$), in particular one has
> $\big| \frac{a}{|a|} - \frac{b}{|b|} \big| \geq c_\delta$.
> Where $c_\delta > 0$ depends only on $n$ and on $\delta$

But I think that once one proves version 1 then version 2 is an easy consequence

Answer (score 1):

Since only two vectors $\vec {OA}$ and $\vec {OB}$ are involved, we can diagram $O,A,B$ as coplanar points in the 2D plane,  and then use  elementary facts about plane Euclidean geometry.

Fix $\alpha =\angle AOB$ and $AB$.

**Inscribed Angle Lemma.** For a fixed segment $AB$ the locus of all points $C$ for which  the angle $\angle ACB =\alpha$   is a pair of congruent circular arcs from $A$ to $B$.  This locus is symmetric across the line L that is the perpendicular bisector of $AB$.

(Proof in appendix).

**Proof of lecture's first covering lemma.**

As you vary $C\in L$, you see that the hypotheses $AC<AB$  forces $C$ to lie inside an equilateral triangle whose sides have length $AB$. And the smallest possible angle that can be subtended in such cases is $\alpha= \pi/3$. This gives the lower bound for angle stated in the lecture you cited.

**Appendix. Complex-analytic proof of the inscribed angle lemma**. The locus can be regarded as the set of all points $z$  in the complex plane for which $\alpha = |Arg (\frac{(a-z)}{(b-z)})|$.  (This follows from the fact that if we use polar notation to write $ a-z= r_1 e^{i \theta _1}$ and $b-z= r_2 e^{i \theta_2}$ then their quotient is a real multiple of $e^{i (\theta_1-\theta_2)}$ and the argument of this expression is $\Delta \theta=\alpha$.)

The linear-fractional map $w= \frac{a-z}{b-z}$ maps circles and lines to circles or lines; the same is true of the inverse map.
However, the locus associated to $\alpha$ is obviously not a line! The two rays $Arg w= \pm \alpha$ must correspond to subsets of two circles. After a translation, rotation,  and dilation in the $z$ plane we can reduce to the special case  in which $a$ and $b$ are the conjugate symmetric pair $a,b=e^{\pm I \alpha/2}$; then confirm that in this case the locus is a pair of circular arcs symmetric under reflection  across both coordinate axes. Do this by finding the inverse map and computing the image of the ray $w= t e^{i \alpha}$ in the $z$ plane.)

P.S. There are of course other ways to prove the

[Inscribed Angle Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4004085/proved-that-angle-subtended-by-a-circle-at-centre-is-double-at-any-other-point-o)

but many have the logical shortcoming of merely showing that the locus is some unspecified  **subset** of the union of two congruent circles. The subtlety is that one should determine exactly what that subset is.